# Triggering the select "drum" in iOS through Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, dom-events

I have a site which has custom replacements for the select tags (thinks madlib). Select tags are still there, just get hidden by Javascript. This is a design decision, not subject to change for the purposed of this question.

In iOS, however, we should use the select "drum" when making a choice. However, I can't seem to fire the right event to get it to come up when the field is clicked.

```
...
  $("li.option",$ul).click(function($ev) {
  $ev.stopPropagation() 
  var $el = $(this).parents(".custom_select");
  if( $is_mobile ){
    $("select",$el).trigger("touchstart"); 
  }else{
    [do other webby stuff]
  }
...
```

1. Is "touchstart" the right event? "Click" doesn't work.
2. Do I have to have the select visible for the event to fire?

Missing anything else here? I'm getting no error, just no success.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for iOS5 is to use their ability to recognize the type="date" and leave it alone.

For Android, still not supported.